# Is it possible to develop on React Native only on Windows?

Tags: react-native

That is, I will use Android Studio on Windows. First, I will write code and test it in an emulator or on a real Android smartphone. Then, when the application is ready, I will place it in the Play Market for Android smartphones. And for iPhones, I'll send the code to a friend who has a Macbook. He will simply compile it and place it in the App Store (without changing my code). That is, if I write one code for Android and it works well there, is it then possible to just place it on the Macbook in the App Store? So I don't have a Macbook. But now I can develop applications on React Native and run them on an Android smartphone. Is it possible to use a friend's Macbook just to host an app on the App Store (not for development)?

Comment: There will be things that look good, and run smoothly on Android, but will be a complete mess on ios. And you can't debug ios problems on windows, so you better get a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but to publish the iOS app on the App Store, **you need the MacBook first**, and then you need to follow the below steps:

1. Open the code in Xcode, the development tool for iOS apps.
2. You can compile the code, package the application, and generate the necessary binary file for iOS.
3. Your friend can then sign in to their own Apple Developer account and
   submit the application to the App Store on your behalf.
4. You will need to go through the necessary steps, such as providing app
   details, screenshots, and app metadata.
5. Once the application is approved by Apple, it will be available on the App Store for users to download and install on their iPhones.